# Why changing R version from global options won't affect R version used in the console?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to figure out which version of R is currently being used by Rstudio. I changed the R version under: tools/global options/general/ R sessions/ R version.
But the version being used by the console seems not affected. I also tried restarting the R session under: Session/ Restart R. Running R.version in console prints the version 4.0.5 yet I have changed the version of R from global options.
here is a screenshot of what I see on Rsutio.

[image]

Comment: My version of Rstudio says "You need to quit and reopen Rstudio in order for this change to take effect" if you change the R version. Have you done that?

Comment: Thank you Miff! It works!
I had not tried that! I'm still a noob :)